# How to copy items of listbox to items of a combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to copy all the items in a listbox to items of a combobox on runtime so need help

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of data is in the listbox/combobox? You alluded to them both having data in reply to Mitch. A better explanation or some code if you can't seem to explain it could go a long way here.

Comment: My problem was that my combobox elements we databounded to a table in database then when ever i clicked to select some value in it.My form just hung up the system. So i copied all of them to listbox from where i could extract the data.If the combobox is not databound the method by Phaedrus works fine or other conventions but generates a problem by not giving the value as text in items but some wrong string system.datarowview.....

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
     comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you are populating the list control via the 'DataSource' property remember to set the source listbox 'DisplayMember' and 'ValueMember' properties:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
listBox1.ValueMember = "ValueMember";
```

and also the target combobox properties to the same values:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ValueMember";
```

When an object is added to the list the listbox checks the 'DisplayMember' property. If the value of 'DisplayMember' doesn't exist or has its value set to an empty string the ToString() method is called on the object contained in the list item to obtain the text to display in the list.

Comment: it gives u text as system.data.dataview....... stuff 
thats what i get every time i try it is the issue i am trying to resolve here

Comment: for loop works fine for me, what if i want to copy certain text to another listbox like i have text "My name | moxet" i want to copy text after | only.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the combobox's datasource to the same one the Listbox is using?

Comment: When i do that it selects only first value it finds for combobox and 
rest are not included :s

Comment: even though i do that i need to get the values in that list box also 
and then merge some values of list boxes in that combobox thats the problem here